# Redis.windows.conf vs Redis.windows-service.conf

Tags: redis

I download `Redis-x64-3.2.100.zip` from [Here](https://github.com/microsoftarchive/redis/releases/tag/win-3.2.100), when i extract it i see two files `redis.windows.conf` and `redis.windows-service.conf`, i compare these two files they really similar, except in `logfile` and `syslog-enabled` and `syslog-ident redis`, and when i want install the Redis i should change configuration on `redis.windows-service.conf`, not `redis.windows.conf`.

so what is the diff between  `redis.windows.conf` and `redis.windows-service.conf`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`redis.windows-service.conf` is meant to be run as a service/daemon. This means that it is meant to be run in the background and managed by the OS (started on reboot, restarted if it crashes, etc).

And `redis.windows.conf` is meant to be run from the command line or a script and managed in user space.

The only substantive difference between the two, as you have pointed out, is that the service hooks into the windows syslog, which is a really good idea for services, but usually unnecessary for normal processes.

Whichever one you choose, you'll probably need to tweak it for your own purposes. They are just around as samples.